# Converting digits, generated by weblog service, to Arabic form

Tags: html

sorry if this is irrelevance :-)

I need to write something in my html code to convert digits of form `0123456789` to `۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹` (Persian digits uni06F0..uni06F9).

the number of visitors is generated by blog service. and I want to convert its digits to Arabic.

Counter:

```
تعداد بازدیدکنندگان : <BlogSky:Weblog Counter /> نفر
```

the Persian part of above code mean 'Number of visitors' and 'Persons' (from left to right). but digits are represented in latin (0123...).
Is it possible to write something like a function in html? i want it to be a global one for using in weblogs.

**Note:** I don't know anything about web programming languages.  I'm not sure about language of above code. (html?)

Comment: -1 for the "and don't want to learn." Contrary to what seems to be the popular opinion, this is not a we-do-your-work. Go hire someone.

Comment: @ivans: Ok. you are right. 'I have to learn'. so could you teach me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Html) only describes the structure of the document. You'll have to use [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javascript) - a client-side language that allows you to do what you need, ie manipulate DOM tree - in that case.

Here you've got an example of code that replaces `0...9` into `۰...۹` in given String:

```
myString.replace(/\d/g, function(matches) {
    return String.fromCharCode("\u06F0".charCodeAt(0) + (matches[0] * 1));
})
```

So basically what you need now is to fetch text from document and replace it by itself but modified with above code:

```
//HTML
<p id="digits">0123456789</p>

//JavaScript:
var text = document.getElementById("digits").firstChild;
text.nodeValue = text.nodeValue.replace(/\d/g, function(matches) {
    return String.fromCharCode("\u06F0".charCodeAt(0) + (matches[0] * 1));
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand but will try to write. It seems that there is no way else than learning basics of web programming...